# When to choose DB4o over SQLite in Android Development

Tags: android, android-sqlite, db4o

I am looking to switch from SQLite to DB4o for Android application , I have read couple of tutorial how to use DB4o in Android but not sure how efficient it is in case of Android, Please help me if you have used DB4o for android or know anything about it.

1. which one should I choose in case database is big or small ?
2. DB4o performance over SQLite ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[db4o OVER 500 TIMES FASTER THAN SQLITE](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/db4o-500x-faster-than-sqlite-td32230.html)

also Look at Here; you yourself will decide :

http://polepos.sourceforge.net/results/html/barcelona_write.html

Comment: Thanks brother , Please let me know if you know any tool or manager to open DB4o file for debugging.